# handling of space and newline

Tags: linux, bash, shell, newlines

Assuming user has 5 processes started, what is queried with below sentences:

```
cuser=`whoami`
a="`ps -C process -o user= | grep $cuser`"
echo $a
user user user user user
```

vs.

```
echo "`ps -C process -o user= | grep $cuser`"
user
user
user
user
user
```

Then it looks like in the 1st case the 'newline' or '\n' is converted to spaces, which seems a good idea.

It looks hard to see how space and newlines are handled in the shell in different situations.

It might need a complete manual for checking how spaces and newlines are handled in each occasion.

Any advice for how they are handled in each occasion?

Here pls. notice that 'newline' is converted into 'space'.

echo "$a" would then seem to preserve the newlines. This is then
maybe echo-command properties to convert newlines to spaces.

Comment: The shell subjects `echo $a` to _word splitting_ which converts all runs of whitespace to a single blank.  The use of double-quotes, as in `echo "$a"`, would suppress that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't trust echo; use `declare -p` to inspect a variable's contents.

In short:

- Quoted strings (including any sort of variable expansions within double-quotes) preserve all whitespace. The entire string is sent as a single argument to `echo`.

  ```
  $ foo="one   two 'three four'"

  $ ~/bin/args "$foo"
  argv[0] = args
  argv[1] = one   two 'three four'

  $ ~/bin/args '$foo'
  argv[0] = args
  argv[1] = $foo
  ```
- Unquoted strings or expansions *are* subject to [word-splitting](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/wordsplit); each IFS-separated word becomes a separate argument given to `echo`, and the echo command re-joins all its arguments using a single space as separator.

  ```
  $ foo="one   two 'three four'"

  $ ~/bin/args $foo
  argv[0] = args
  argv[1] = one
  argv[2] = two
  argv[3] = 'three
  argv[4] = four'
  ```
- The right-hand side of variable assignments is an exception to the rule; expansions therein always work as if they were double-quoted. These are equivalent:

  ```
  foo=$(ps ...)
  foo="$(ps ...)"

  foo=`ps ...`
  foo="`ps ...`"
  ```

  (Array assignments like `foo=(...)` are an exception *to* the exception and each array item needs to be quoted again.)

See also:

- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo
- https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting
- https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/wordsplit
- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
- [With Bash variables, what is the difference between $myvar and "$myvar"? (Specific odd behavior)](https://superuser.com/questions/1313649/with-bash-variables-what-is-the-difference-between-myvar-and-myvar-specif)

Comment: There are plenty of other threads about newlines in $var, but all of them just tell you to use quotes and don't really explain anything else at all.